# why this typescript overload example do not work

Tags: typescript

I was learning typescript from https://www.typescriptlang.org,and in this page https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html have same overloads code

```
let suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];

function pickCard(x: {suit: string; card: number; }[]): number;
function pickCard(x: number): {suit: string; card: number; };
function pickCard(x): any {
    // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
    // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
    if (typeof x == "object") {
        let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
        return pickedCard;
    }
    // Otherwise just let them pick the card
    else if (typeof x == "number") {
        let pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13);
        return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 };
    }
}

let myDeck = [{ suit: "diamonds", card: 2 }, { suit: "spades", card: 10 }, { suit: "hearts", card: 4 }];
let pickedCard1 = myDeck[pickCard(myDeck)];
alert("card: " + pickedCard1.card + " of " + pickedCard1.suit);

let pickedCard2 = pickCard(15);
alert("card: " + pickedCard2.card + " of " + pickedCard2.suit);
```

I paste it to http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAzgrglmKEC8EDaAiAFiAhgJ0QwBoIMoAHXAExChLIGNgYAje0jauXAWwHsAdtXoBdANwAoSQDMYgxmDhCIFOIwDWAYQLUAFAA8AXBADesBCahh8cQQHNxERrpOCYvViHxOAvmlEASjcPLx9ZeUVlQVV1bV1DEM9vYLMLMCsbO0dnVwh3ZJ8IXyk5BSUVNU0dfH0DVNxBAE8zSQh2iAB6TogtHE0IMH5oEBAIOBkIAHcQAHJ8Man+fA1s6YQsCEaIflYAKxBFToJ8XCa2ju7xyah+UjAcFvtcADcxmCQHsdoBxuppubAYCxAZfXK1C7tCYQPRgJoUED8SYGFCoDC7A6KDCBVodPEQUCQKoaEDUGr-VAAWVwDwAdDJgPxlnpqXTTsJ+Lw9DiAFQQAy00AOB6BKT4joLMAwfAxYmk8lijq+SFdHoAeS++CmcCgYz2H0ghMGOF4II0xrGLgheJAwF11xhcIRSP5qLIBTC2Nx4oJ4DNpIAyvBIFSaVh6YzmSiegBGADMopVeMl0pipmgwaswagaDl1CDCFEpCt1BMKIApBB48VFe1lcrJEbeE0ACKHc2oNDp9ImLg8ATCDjg0sQABMxVI3czZEoNDoDBLJhjAAYJ2YM5YyDgCERi3kACzFCSNv158kxlAQZttzS5uLkvTX9uBY+4UCEPQYRdkCAAan9ZK6DGtIln+P4uhgYFnkBtLpImJ5EnE8q6OOqDEg+MYAKyJm+3hgJ+36Qf+0G1KOIG6GBkEQVBSGAaRsHBqKQA

and something is wrong,is the document wrong?

Comment: What did not work in your example? I've seen only one error - `Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type`, and it is solved by, well, explicitly typing `x` as `any`.

Comment: @Cerberus after change to x:any,it works ,first i was think its official document,it can't be wrong,i was wrong.

Comment: Well, this is an error only when the corresponding setting (`noImplicitAny`) is enabled. The documentation might skip this step for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
function pickCard(x): any {
```

to

```
function pickCard(x: number | {suit: string; card: number; }[]): any {
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an implicit any as the error states.

But this is not necessarily something you don't want.

As @Cerberus point out in comment you can just type `x in`any`

or you can pimp your options in the playground (go to options and unselect the checkbox `no implicit any`) so that you can run the code as it is written ion the tutorial